# ObjectiveC selector to monotouch function mapping

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, selector, xamarin

Recently I've came across a file, in which for a given objective c selector you could find equivalent mono touch function. Have anybody came across to this kind of file? I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miguel's used to generate a [rosetta](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html) for this. I'm not sure how up-to-date is this google'd version.

IIRC you should be able to use Xamarin's local documentation (MacDoc) to search and find the managed method for any selector.

Comment: Thanks that was the file I was looking for :)) , I'll try to use Xamarin's doc. Thanks